# "errorMessage": "Invalid shorthand property initializer"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

i have tried this many time but pretty new to node.js so little confused that how we can take the input from users via request body for these inputs :Customer_Full_Name = event.body.Customer_Full_Name,Customer_adress = event.body.Customer_adress,customerID_number = event.body.customerID_number,CurrentDate = event.body.CurrentDate,
Digital_Signature = event.body.Digital_Signature

```
module.exports.pdf = async (event, context, callBack) => 
{
    const data = {
        Customer_Full_Name = event.body.Customer_Full_Name,
        Customer_adress = event.body.Customer_adress,
        customerID_number = event.body.customerID_number,
        CurrentDate = event.body.CurrentDate,
        Digital_Signature = event.body.Digital_Signature
    }
```

but now i'm getting test logs like this

```
    {
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid shorthand property initializer",
  "trace": [
    "/var/task/pdf.js:24",
    "        Customer_Full_Name = event.body.Customer_Full_Name,",
    "        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",
    "",
    "SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer",
    "    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
    "    at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397)",
    "    at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397)",
    "    at Module._require.i.require (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:73397)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)"
  ]
}
```

my test file:

```
{
  "body": {
    "Customer_Full_Name": "Swapnil Bais",
    "Customer_adress": "Near To Haldiram, Besa, Nagpur ",
    "customerID_number": "12345",
    "CurrentDate": "12-12-21",
    "Digital_Signature": "Swapnil K Bais"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the event format forwarded by the APIGateway here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format

So to get the body parameters you just need `event.body`, in your case `event.body.Customer_Full_Name` or `event.body['Customer_Full_Name']` supposing that the body has the following format `{"Customer_Full_Name": "bla", ...}`

Also, an extra recommendation for you is to only copy/paste the interesting parts related to the question you are asking, not the entire thing. Here, the business logic of the function is just a distraction and makes it harder for reviewers to understand the question.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I have tried that but         Customer_Full_Name = event.queryStringParameters.Customer_Full_Name,
        Customer_adress = event.queryStringParameters.Customer_adress,
        customerID_number = event.queryStringParameters.customerID_number,
        CurrentDate = event.queryStringParameters.CurrentDate,
        Digital_Signature = event.queryStringParameters.Digital_Signature

Comment: but getting this logs : {
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid shorthand property initializer",
  "trace": [
    "/var/task/pdf.js:19",
    "        Customer_Full_Name = event.queryStringParameters.Customer_Full_Name,",
    "        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",
    "",
    "SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer",
    "    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)",
    ........
}

Comment: {
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Invalid shorthand property initializer",
  "trace": [
    "/var/task/pdf.js:24",
    "        Customer_Full_Name = event.body.Customer_Full_Name,",
    "        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^",
    "",

Answer (score 0):

Got The Answer:

Actually, I have to use the ":" instead of "=":

```
Customer_Full_Name: event.body['Customer_Full_Name'],
Customer_adress: event.body['Customer_adress'],
customerID_number: event.body['customerID_number'],
CurrentDate: event.body['CurrentDate'],
Digital_Signature: event.body['Digital_Signature']
```